# How to create a copy of a file immediately when it's created?

Tags: adb, file-system, linux, shell

I have an Android app that will create a file in `/data/` and immediately delete it. I want to know how can I catch this file or create a copy or even disable user permissions to delete a file? I have root access to the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `busybox inotifyd`. Your kernel must be built with `CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y` for this to work. You can confirm with:

```
~# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep INOTIFY
```

Or the existence of `/proc/sys/fs/inotify` directory. `/proc/config.gz` may not exist on all devices depending on kernel build configuration.

Let's say `/data/data/com.xyz/files/` is the directory you want to watch. Write a script to execute when a file or directory is created in the given directory:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# remove first argument: EVENT
shift

# create directiry to backup files
mkdir -p /sdcard/backup/

# copy newly created file/directory
[ -e "$1/$2" ] || exit
cp -av "$1/$2" /sdcard/backup/
```

Place the script at `/data/local/tmp/copy_it.sh` and `chmod a+x`. Now execute:

```
~# inotifyd /data/local/tmp/copy_it.sh /data/data/com.xyz/files:n
```

Note `:n` at the end of line, which is the event that reports that a file/directory is created in watched directory. However watches are not established recursively.

For more complex operations, use `inotifywait` from [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1417732/863965).

**RELATED:** [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214284/218526)