# How to create a copy of a file immediately when it's created?

Tags: linux, shell

I have an Android app that will create a file and immediately delete it. I want to know how can I catch this file or create a copy or even disable user permissions to delete a file. I have root access to the device.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to monitor a directory for changes, at least sometimes... I'd start by searching for that

Comment: @Xen2050 i find the answer i can do it with inotify but because the linux is on android i can't install it easily im trying to install it

Comment: I think inotify's right, no idea how to get it working with android either. Possibly a program/script that just reads a directory every second & immediately copies new files might work too, but might be resource intensive & slow things down

Comment: @Xen2050 its on an emulator so i don't care about performance

Comment: Could just loop some find/ls & `sleep 0.25` commands then, maybe with an array of found files, then when it changes do something?

Comment: @Xen2050 there is a great app named busy-box and the app have all the important packages including inotify and its super easy to use and install too

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using `inotifywait` from [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki). Your kernel must be built with `CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y` for this to work. You can confirm with:

```
~# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep INOTIFY
```

Or the existence of `/proc/sys/fs/inotify` directory. `/proc/config.gz` may not exist on all devices depending on kernel build configuration.

Let's say `/data/data/com.xyz/files/` is the directory you want to watch.

```
~$ mkdir -p /sdcard/backup/
~# inotifywait -rm --format '%w%f' -e create /data/data/com.xyz/files/ |
while read file
do
    [ -f "$file" ] && cp -av "$file" /sdcard/backup/
done
```

`-e create` is the event that reports that a file/directory is created in watched directory, `--format` is to get filename with complete path, `-m` is to watch continuously and `-r` establishes watches recursively. `-d` can daemonize the process i.e. run in background.

All newly created files in watched directory or in any sub-directory will be copied to `/sdcard/backup`.

You can also use `busybox inotifyd` for simple use case as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209465/218526). For more options see [inotifywait(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html).

**RELATED:** [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214284/218526)

Comment: hi [link](https://github.com/jrummyapps/inotify-android-tools) the easiest way is to work with this c library

Comment: I could not make this way to work but the c script is worked just fine and a lot easier but maybe the problem was with my execution.

Comment: hi im steel stuck can you please help me a little bit? im really confused i can't execute this c script either

Comment: Well, there is no reason fo both of my methods I mentioned here and the other one to not work. They are very straightforward. And C is not a scripting language. What you have written is a program in C language, which needs to be compiled into an executable binary using some compiler.

Comment: hi, I got the file with termux inotify but its a .so file not dex

Comment: @Amin Looks like you only got the library (libinotify), not the command-line tools (inotify-tools). Anyway you never get dex file, dex is Java code, and is not executed on command-line level. Command-line tools are native executables.

Comment: All Android kernels should support inotify tools because Android API contains `FileObserver` which bases on inotify. Hence any official kernel have to support it otherwise it could not pass the Google compatibility test.

Comment: is there a way to replace the file immediately after its creation?

Comment: @ddddavidee replace with what? `inotify` informs you as soon as the file is created (or modified, or deleted). Now it's up to you what you do with the file (or with something else).

Comment: I have an app creating a file and loading it in memory. I would like to replace it before being loaded...