# Getting "CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "inotifywait": library "libnotifytools.so" not found. " when tyring to run a script that uses the inotifywait binary

Tags: root-access, sync, shell, mount, bash

The script is here: https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/com.piyushgarg.rclone/blob/master/binary/syncd.sh

The code that I do not believe is working is this:

```
while true; do
    if [[ ! -e ${SYNC_PENDING} ]]; then
        ${HOME}/inotifywait "/storage/emulated/${PROFILE}/${SYNCDIR}" -e modify,create,moved_to,close_write -q >> /dev/null 2>&1 && touch ${SYNC_PENDING}
    fi
```

When I execute the `inotifywait` binary as a standalone, I get this message:

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "inotifywait": library "libnotifytools.so" not found.

Does this indicate that I am missing a library? How can I solve the issue?

Comment: looks like a typo, try a symlink libnotifytools.so -> libinotifytools.so

Comment: You can manually use `busybox inotifyd` or `inotifywait` from commandline: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209585/218526. Here is the statically linked `inotifywait` binary for aarch64: https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=10763459528675584729